# How to set the "Positive" and "Negative" colors on the Waterfall graph using Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Im using Google Apps Scripts to modify an existing Waterfall graph inside of a sheet. I'm able to change the color of the series dynamically, but when i try to set the colors for "Positive" and "Negative" options im unable to get the right options to get my desired result.

I believe that i'm just not expanding the JSON correctly and I cannot find the documentation of how each option in the visual/GUI builder is transcribed into text.

```
exampleChart = exampleChart.modify()
      .setOption('series.0.color', 'red')
      .setOption('series.0.positive.color', 'black')
      .build();
sheet.updateChart(exampleChart);
```

[Resulting change in chart options of the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcyPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when I searched for the parameter for changing the positive and negative colors of the Waterfall chart, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. So, at that case, I used Sheets API. When Sheets API is used for changing the colors of the Waterfall chart, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

In this sample script, the 1st chart in "Sheet1" is used. So, please modify this for your actual situation. Each color is from your showing script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  var positiveColor = { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 }; // red
  var negativeColor = { red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 }; // black
  var subtotalColor = { red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5 }; // gray

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // In this sample, the 1st chart in the sheet is used.
  var chartId = chart.getChartId();
  var chartObj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [sheetName] }).sheets[0].charts.find(e => e.chartId == chartId);
  delete chartObj.position;
  var obj = [{ k: "positiveColumnsStyle", v: positiveColor }, { k: "negativeColumnsStyle", v: negativeColor }, { k: "subtotalColumnsStyle", v: subtotalColor }];
  obj.forEach(({ k, v }) => {
    if (k && v) {
      var t = chartObj.spec.waterfallChart.series[0];
      if (!t[k]) {
        t[k] = { colorStyle: { rgbColor: v } };
      } else {
        t[k].colorStyle = { rgbColor: v };
      }
    }
  });
  var requests = [{ updateChartSpec: { spec: chartObj.spec, chartId } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

- In this case, `subtotalColumnsStyle` is also set. If you don't want to use this, please remove it from the script.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following sample situation is obtained.

##### Before:

[image]

##### After:

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)
- [ColorStyle](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ColorStyle)